How to compare the impact of two methods of introducing adsgoogle.js on web page performance and loading speed?
For example, if a web page has three ad slots, will there be a big speed difference between the two methods?
Method 1：
Import adsbygoogle.js only once in the  tag:
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

After that, each ad unit in the page will no longer import the adsbygoogle.js file,only introduce:
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:block"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx"
data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx"
data-ad-format="auto"
data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

Method 2：
Each ad unit introduces the adsbygoogle.js file:
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle" 
style="display:block" 
data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" 
data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxx" 
data-ad-format="auto" 
data-full-width-responsive=" true"></ins>
<script> 
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); 
</script>

I used PageSpeed ​​Insights to analyze the performance of both, and it seems that there is not much difference。
You are welcome to suggest ways to test the performance of the two methods.
